# Flutter ways to switch between material apps or reload main function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I would like to have a clear separation of concerns between user enroll flow and the rest of the app. To do that I have created a MaterialApp for Enroll flow and a MaterialApp for the main application. When the user is done signing up - they should be directed to the main app. So something like this:

```
void main() async {

    // ... init and stuff ... //

    if(isUserAccountExists){
    
        runApp(MultiProvider(
            providers: [
                Provider(create: (context) => DataStorage()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: settingsController),
                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: oauthProvider),
                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: deviceProvider),
                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: messenger),
            ],
            child: MainApp(settingsController: settingsController),
        ),);
    
    } else runApp(EnrollApp());
}
```

My problem is when the user is done signing up, I have no ways to restart the application or reload the `main()` function. (I must restart due to initialization steps that precede the `runApp` call).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flutter_phoenix](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) to restart your application.

**flutter_phoenix configuration:**

```
dependencies:
    flutter_phoenix: "^1.0.0"

import 'package:flutter_phoenix/flutter_phoenix.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}

Phoenix.rebirth(context);
```

You may follow these steps:

1. After your sign up, call `Phoenix.rebirth(context);` method to restart the application
2. In your splash screen or main widget check the database so that the user is already signed up or not then redirect the user to your ux/view.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract your signup logic in separate `Class`(Widget) to handle which screen to render based on signup status. Something like here:

```
class _SeparationClassState extends State<SeparationClass> {
  bool isUserAccountExists = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // update isUserAccountExists to trigger rebuild
    return Scaffold(
      body: isUserAccountExists
          ? MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                Provider(create: (context) => DataStorage()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: settingsController),
                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: oauthProvider),
                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: deviceProvider),
                ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: messenger),
              ],
              child: MainApp(settingsController: settingsController),
            )
          : EnrollApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

It doesn't needs to be a `StatefulWidget`, you can use `Provider` or `Bloc` pattern to handle signup logic and update your state (and ui) accordingly.